# Delete a file after 20 days in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I am writing a program which generates an XML file. Now I want to save this XML file in a folder and auto delete it after 20 days. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't satisfy your needs? Any code?

Comment: keep your program running, calculating time elapsed and if it's greater than 20 days delete the file.

Comment: you should create some schedulers and remove all files in that folder with more than 20 from created date

Comment: You could use ScheduledExecutorService to schedule a periodic task that checks for old files and deletes them. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Depends on the system. There are easier ways to do this outside of java. eg `schtasks` on windows, `cron` on linux/ unix systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the file attributes, then check if the date is more than 20 days in the past. 
Then you could make another method that iterates over all files, which is easily done with NIO (walkFileTree). you can even read the attribute of last edited, if that could be of importance to you.
This way you wouldn't need to have the program running the whole time, but even if you shut it down and start the process, it will delete outdated files.

Comment: Yes eventually I did it with NIO. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.